# To show that $(X,d)$ is complete.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space such that for each $x \in X$ there exists an $\epsilon _x >0$ with $cl(B(x,\epsilon _x))$ compact, where $cl(A)$ is closure of $A$. To show that $(X,d)$ is complete.

Please help me to do this unable to make a start.

Comment: As you have been on MSE for some time now, you should be aware of the proper asking policy. Users are more likely to offer aid if you provide evidence that you have made an attempt in good faith to solve the problem by yourself. In addition, we can offer more targeted aid if you specify previous attempts you have made, as then we may be able to identify where you are struggling. For more on how to ask questions on this site, please visit http://math.stackexchange.com/help/asking.

Comment: The statement in your question is equivalent the assertion that every [locally compact](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locally_compact_space) metric space is complete; as **ncmathsadist**’s answer shows, this is false. If you reverse the quantifiers in the hypothesis, however, you get a correct result: If there is an $\epsilon>0$ such that $\operatorname{cl}B(x,\epsilon)$ is compact for each $x\in X$, then $X$ is complete. You should try to prove this.

Comment: Your question was put on hold, the message above (and possibly comments) should give an explanation why. You might try to edit your question to address these issues. Note that the next edit puts your post in the review queue, where users can vote to reopen this. (Therefore it would be good to avoid minor edits and improve your question as much as possible with the next edit.)

Comment: is not my question same as yours @BrianM.Scott

Comment: @joymath: No, it is not. In your question there may be a different $\epsilon_x$ for each $x\in X$; in mine there is **one** $\epsilon$ that works for **every** $x$.

Answer (score 5):

What about $(0,1)$. It seems to satisfy this property and not be compact.